Trouble with reduction of a double integral
I want to compute
$$
I = \iint_{C}\frac{x}{1 + {\rm e}^{y}}\,
{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y
$$
where $C= \left\{(x, y)\in \mathbb{R^{2}} : x\leq 4,\ y\leq 0,\ y + \ln\left(x/2\right) \geq 0\right\}$
I thought that $0 < x \leq4$ (so that the natural log is defined) and $-\ln(x/2) \leq y \leq0$, so $$ I = \int_0^4 \int_{-\ln(x/2)} ^0  \frac{x} {1+e^y} dy dx$$
WolframAlpha says that this integral is approximately equal to $1.0465$. I solved it and got $I = 6 \ln(3) - 8 \ln(2)$, which is the exact value given by WolframAlpha. However, according to the authors of the book, the solution should be $I = 6 \ln(3) - 6 \ln(2) - 1 ≈ 1.4328$.
I am confident that I solved correctly the second integral of this post (since I got the same solution as WolframAlpha), so I fear that I was wrong with the bounds of integration. Can someone please tell me if the book is wrong or explain to me my mistakes? Thanks in advance.

$y$ must be negative, which means $2\leq x\leq 4$

@SineoftheTime I see, I didn't consider the inequality $-\ln(x/2) \leq 0$

Actually, I'm the one who made the mistake: $x\in [2,4]$

@SineoftheTime that's true, I have just realised it. I deleted my previous comment since it was wrong - thank you too

@NinadMunshi I got your point, thanks for your help

From $-\log(x/2)\le y \le 0$, you have in particular $-\log(x/2)\le 0$ i.e $x\ge 2$. Since $x\le 4$, $x$ varies in the interval $[2,4]$, hence the correct bounds are:
$$I=\int_2^4 \int_{-\log(x/2)}^0 \frac{x}{1+e^y} \mathrm dy \mathrm dx $$
